# Manifolds with Homology groups that are not finitely generated

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds

I know that compact manifolds have finitely generated homology groups.
I read somewhere that the same is not true for arbitrary manifolds.

What would be an example of a manifold with homology groups that are not finitely generated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a plane, remove an infinite number of points, the first homology group of this manifold is infinite

Answer (score 0):

Take an infinite disjoint union of compact manifolds.